# Mongo using $graphLookup inside of $graphLookup to resolve nested references

Tags: mongodb

I have a reference in a referenced object I want to resolve.
This is my setup I have 3 collections.

collection 1 posts, I use match+projection to get a single post document from this collection.

```
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": "5B60"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "name": 1,
      "author": 1,
      "parts": 1,
      "description": 1,
      "createdAt": 1,
      "updatedAt": 1
    }
  },
```

posts contain a part field which contains an array of parts id-s.

```
_id:"5B60"
picture:Array
parts: [0:"LhNuJd15_X7"]
name:"Test :)"
description:"strin"
author:"e3fc0911-b708-481e-b4fb-8c1c60a57c3d"
createdAt:2020-10-30T22:08:52.433+00:00
updatedAt:2020-11-04T17:51:36.981+00:00
```

I resolve this with graphLookup and replace the `parts` id array with the resolved objects.

```
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "parts",
      "connectFromField": "parts",
      "connectToField": "_id",
      "as": "parts",
      "startWith": "$parts"
    }
  },
```

now parts are replaced by resolved objects instead of the reference id-s

```
_id:"5B60"
picture:Array
parts:{
  0:Object
    _id:"LhNuJd15_X7"
    name:"QuadH H1"
    template:"4Mdf9i0fh"
    picture:Array
    commentReplies:Array
    createdAt:2020-10-29T21:52:51.063+00:00
    updatedAt:2020-11-06T14:00:37.401+00:00
}
name:"test :)"
description:"strin"
createdAt:2020-10-30T22:08:52.433+00:00
updatedAt:2020-11-04T17:51:36.981+00:00
```

This is where it gets tricky, now `parts` contains parts objects, and these objects contain a template field, this is an id that I would want to be resolved and replaced instead of the template field.

I tried using projection, I can resolve it but I can't insert it into the parts.$part.template field as $ cant be used for `as` field.

```
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "templates",
      "connectFromField": "template",
      "connectToField": "_id",
      "as": "$parts.template",
      "startWith": "$parts.template"
    }
  }
```

I have added a screenshot of the aggregation as shows in MongoDB compass.

[image: mongodb aggregation]

How can I solve this? I resolve one array of documents, want to iterate through it, and resolve a nested array of documents while keeping the structure.

Comment: i'm confused with the syntax.  how do u get this
`parts: [0:"LhNuJd15_X7"]` ?

Comment: I added a screenshot, I was trying to describe how each step in the pipeline was operating but the screenshot probably shows it better. in posts the `parts` field is a array of (part reference) id-s, I am not using mongodb objectIds but string Ids. The ids are stored in the document and get retrieved with the posts.